# How do I get as many enemies as possible to attack me in 1 round from a distance?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, tactics

On my ranged rogue I have the Daring Gamble utility power, which, once activated, gives me CA **for the rest of the encounter** on any enemies that attack me before the start of my next turn.

How can I best get as many enemies as possible to attack me (from a distance, because I'm ranged and don't want to be in melee) during that turn?

Comment: Have you tried shooting them?

Comment: What options have you explored so far?

Answer (score 6):

Here's the deal. you're already an attractive target being the squishy rogue.

However, you're missing the point of this power. This power is intended for an artful dodger rogue to go draw an opportunity attack *from the entire encounter*. She gets a huge bonus (and with the right equipment load out, it can be even higher). So light off this one, and go move past everyone (or at least the big bad). And enjoy your CA for the rest of the encounter (if you're not dazed, stunned, dominated or yah know...dead).

Another option, if you're not into eating 100 opportunity attacks, is to take the Guardian theme and use Guardian's counter when a nearby ally gets hit. You get a free MBA attack and the attack hits you so you get CA for the rest of the encounter. This doesn't really fit your build, but it's something.

The last two options are to either grant CA (give a nice +2 bonus to hit you), or to find yourself a mark (you don't care about enforcing it) that will disincentivize attacking anyone but you. This is doable from range if you use something like a predatory weapon (5 squares). Granting CA is a bit harder, but you can usually find a way without too much trouble.

Ultimately though, if you stand toe to toe with a baddie in melee, you're gonna get roughed up enough to make this power worth it. You're already an attractive target, drawing agro shouldn't be an issue for you. Doing it from range is harder, but you should still get attacked about 1/round. Again, you're a squishy rogue.